# Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of matches played in a knockout tournament with $n$ teams, where $n$ is a power of $2$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of matches played in a knockout tournament with $n$ teams, where $n$ is a power of $2$

I have already found a recurrence relation based on the two parts:
$1$. There are $\frac{n}{2}$ matches played in the first round.
$2$. The next round there are $a_{n/2}$ matches played in sub tournaments.

Thus, the recurrence relation for this problem is:$$a_n=a_{n/2}+\frac{n}{2}$$With a base case of $a_2=1$

However, I am now stuck on how exactly to solve this, since it is non-homogenous in nature due to the $\frac{n}{2}$. I know that in the end, it should end up being:$$a_n=n-1$$Since that, for example, it logically takes $63$ matches to determine a champion of $64$ teams. But I don't know how that solution is derived.

Comment: Let $m=\log_2{n}$, then $\log_2{n/2}=m-1$. Now can you solve in terms of $m$? Note that your $a_n$ is not defined when $n$ is not a power of two, so you have to reindex.

Comment: Where are $m =$ $log_2$$n$ and $log_2$$n/2=m-1$ coming from? Also, what do you mean by reindexing?

Comment: You are defining $a_n$ to be the number of matches played in a knockout tournament with n teams, **where n is a power of two**. However, when you are dealing with $n=7$, say, what will you do? $a_7$ can't be defined, because $7$ is not a power of two. Hence, by reindexing I mean, change $n$ to such a variable $m$ such that $a_m$ makes sense for every natural number index. When you put $m=\log_2{n}$, then you are able to redefine your problem as follows:  $a_m$ will now be the number of matches played in a knockout tournament with $2^m$ teams.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand where this random variable $m$ is coming into to play, or why.

Comment: I shall reply in an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get rid of homogeneity, but as I said, you need to reindex because you want the sequence to be well defined for the index not a power of two.

The relation you have obtained above, can now be stated more slickly: $a_0=1$ and $a_m=a_{m-1} + 2^{m-1}$.

This **does not get rid of homogeneity**: you can't get rid of that. But, you have another tool: you know the answer. The best thing you can do now, is proof by induction, but that's if you don't understand the proof I am giving below anyway.

This way is much easier.Watch this:

$a_m = a_{m-1} + 2^{m-1} = a_{m-2}+2^{m-2}+2^{m-1} = a_{0} + 2^{1} + 2^2 + ... + 2^{m-1}= 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^{m-1} = 2^m - 1$.

I just telescoped the series, and obtained your result. It goes to show that even if the relation is non-homogeneous, it can still be solved in this manner.

Comment: Thank you, this extended answer cleared things up a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: In your expansion of $a_m$, you meant to write $a_0 = 1$ rather than $a_0 = 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ah,absolutely. Thank you.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  I was referring to the line where you wrote \begin{align*} a_m & = a_{m - 1} + 2^{m - 1}\\ & = a_{m - 2} + 2^{m - 2} + 2^{m - 1}\\ & = a_0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{m - 1}\\ & = \color{red}{0} + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{m - 1}\\ & = 2^m - 1 \end{align*}  The $0$ should be a $1$.

Comment: Edited, sir. Thank you once again.